# NAudio wrong mp3 duration when calculating by AverageBytesPerSecond

Tags: c#, mp3, naudio, duration

I tested the duration which is calculated using `Mp3WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond` when streaming mp3.

```
AverageBytesPerSecond: 64 kbps
Content Length: 2436943 bytes
Duration: 2436943 / (64 / 8 * 1024) = 297 seconds
```

But this is not correct, because the actual duration of the mp3 is 191 seconds. I can't understand why this is happening. Is something wrong in my calculation?

> Mp3 Informations

[image]

> Code to get WaveFormat of the source mp3

```
HttpWebRequest req = SendRequest(url, 0, 0);
HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
size = resp.ContentLength;
Stream str = resp.GetResponseStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
byte[] storer = new byte[1024 * 100];
int bytesRead = 0;
int total = 0;
while ((bytesRead = str.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
     Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, storer, total, bytesRead);
     total += bytesRead;
     Mp3Frame frame = Mp3Frame.LoadFromStream(new MemoryStream(storer));
     if (frame == null) continue;

     format = new Mp3WaveFormat(frame.SampleRate, frame.ChannelMode == ChannelMode.Mono ? 1 : 2,
     frame.FrameLength, frame.BitRate);
     decompressor = new AcmMp3FrameDecompressor(format);

     req.Abort();
     resp.Close();
     str.Close();

     break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MP3 files are not always CBR (constant bit rate). So some frames might have a different bitrate. Also an MP3 file can contain non-audio portions, for example it might include album art and various other metadata about the file. So calculations of duration are only an estimate.

Comment: So how can i calculate a specific second's byte offset to make a fast forward or rewind?

Comment: It's not that simple. You can work out how long each "frame" is, and attempt to jump to the the next frame.